# Query c# List to limit children but return parents

Tags: c#, linq

I have a nested list structure with Customers -> Orders -> OrderItems.  I am trying to find a LINQ or other query that will return the Customers and their nested items where the OrderItem quantity = 1.  However, it should not return any Orders or OrderItems where the quantity != 1.

I have tried this:

```
var customers2 = customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderItems.Exists(oi => oi.Quantity == 1)));
```

It correctly returns only Customers with order items quantity = 1, but it also returns all other Orders and Order Items as well.

I can get the desired results with a couple of For-each loops, but I would like to find something more elegant:

```
        foreach (var customer in customers2)
        {
            customer.Orders = customer.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderItems.Exists(oi => oi.Quantity == 1)).ToList();

            foreach (var order in customer.Orders)
            {
                order.OrderItems = order.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.Quantity == 1).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Here is the object structure and some sample data.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public bool Shipped { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer
            {
                CustomerId = 1,
                Name = "Shawn",
                Address = "123 Main Street",
                Orders = new List<Order>()
                {
                    new Order()
                    {
                        OrderId = 100,
                        CustomerId = 1,
                        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Shipped = true,
                        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>()
                        {
                            new OrderItem()
                            {
                                OrderItemId = 200,
                                OrderId = 100,
                                ItemName = "Computer",
                                Quantity = 1
                            },
                            new OrderItem()
                            {
                                OrderItemId = 206,
                                OrderId = 100,
                                ItemName = "Hard Drive",
                                Quantity = 2
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Order()
                    {
                        OrderId = 106,
                        CustomerId = 1,
                        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Shipped = true,
                        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>()
                        {
                            new OrderItem()
                            {
                                OrderItemId = 207,
                                OrderId = 106,
                                ItemName = "Monitor",
                                Quantity = 3
                            },
                            new OrderItem()
                            {
                                OrderItemId = 208,
                                OrderId = 106,
                                ItemName = "DVD Burner",
                                Quantity = 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Customer
            {
                CustomerId = 2,
                Name = "Arianna",
                Address = "456 Main Street",
                Orders = new List<Order>()
                {
                    new Order()
                    {
                        OrderId = 101,
                        CustomerId = 2,
                        OrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                        Shipped = true,
                        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>()
                        {
                            new OrderItem()
                            {
                                OrderItemId = 201,
                                OrderId = 101,
                                ItemName = "barbie",
                                Quantity = 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Customer
            {
                CustomerId = 3,
                Name = "Ryan",
                Address = "789 Main Street",
                Orders = new List<Order>()
                {
                    new Order()
                    {
                        OrderId = 102,
                        CustomerId = 3,
                        OrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5),
                        Shipped = true,
                        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>()
                        {
                            new OrderItem()
                            {
                                OrderItemId = 203,
                                OrderId = 103,
                                ItemName = "Minecraft",
                                Quantity = 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path with

```
var customers2 = customers
    .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderItems.Exists(oi => oi.Quantity == 1)));
```

You just need an additional step as you can't filter the orders and the customers at the same time, you already filtered the customers to get only those you're interested in, now filter the orders themselves

```
var customers2 = customers
    .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderItems.Exists(oi => oi.Quantity == 1)))
    .Select(c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderItems(o => o.OrderItems.Exists(oi => oi.Quantity == 1)));
```

This however leaves you with an ienumerable of ienumerable of orders, and not the customers, but you can't do exactly what you want (retrieve the customers and have their order property changed) as that would change their original order list, what you can do is create an Anonymous type to store both the orders and Customer in your query in the select as such:

```
var customers2 = customers
    .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderItems.Exists(oi => oi.Quantity == 1)))
    .Select(c => new
       {
       Customer = c,
       FilteredOrders =  c.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderItems(o => o.OrderItems.Exists(oi => oi.Quantity == 1))
       });
```

Now you can use this as such

```
foreach(var cust in customers2)
{
   cust.Customer // your original Customer object
   cust.Customer.Orders // your original orders collection for this Customer
   cust.FilteredOrders // only the orders you're interested in for this customer
}
```

Comment: This is thinking in the right direction. I think there's yet one more step here--he said he didn't want any `OrderItem`s to be returned that had more Quantity != 1, too.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there's a shorter solution but this works:

```
var goodCusts = new List<Customer>();

foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    var testCust = customer;

    for (int i = testCust.Orders.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        if (testCust.Orders[i].OrderItems.Count != 1)
            testCust.Orders.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    if (testCust.Orders.Any())
        goodCusts.Add(testCust);        
}
```

It does create a new collection, though.  It just runs through each customer, removes any `Orders` with `OrderItems.Count != 1`, then tests if that customer has any `Orders` left.  If it does, it gets added to the `List<Customer>` results.

Comment: You have to be careful with this solution. Supposing you're using an ORM, it might interpret the removal of those orders from the list as meaning you want it to remove those relationships in the database.

Comment: If need-be you can make a copy of `customer` for `testCust` to bypass that problem.

Comment: I just added the foreach loops that can make this work - just trying to get something more elegant...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @StripplingWarrior I think I have arrived at the answer, though prob still not the most elegant:

```
var customers2 = customers.Where(x => x.Orders != null && x.Orders.Any(y => y.OrderItems != null && y.OrderItems.Any(z => z.Quantity == 1)));

customers2.ToList().ForEach(x => 
{
    x.Orders.ForEach(y => 
    {
        y.OrderItems.RemoveAll(z => z == null || z.Quantity != 1);
    });

    x.Orders.RemoveAll(y => y == null || y.OrderItems.Count == 0);
});

return customers2;
```

Comment: Please read the question again. This answer is not at all what the OP is going for.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Just edited to equal to 1, got it wrong the first time

Comment: I see that. This still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It "works" in that it doesn't throw any exceptions, but if re-read the question, the OP wants to check the `Quantity` property of his `OrderItem`s, not the number of `OrderItem`s on each order. Also, he wants to limit the items returned in the `Orders` and `OrderItems` properties. Take some time to read and understand the other answers, and I think you'll better understand the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This will get all customers with the specific orders where the order items quantity is the desired amount.
To use this it will remove all orderitems that do not have one item quantity. So you need to clone the list before using this function.

```
    public static List<Customer> GetCustomersWithOrderItemQuantity(List<Customer> customers, int quantity)
    {

        var customers2 = customers.TakeWhile(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderItems.Any(oi => oi.Quantity == quantity))).ToList();
        customers2.ForEach(cust => cust.Orders.ForEach(o => o.OrderItems.RemoveAll(oi => oi.Quantity != quantity)));
        return customers2;
    }
```

You can use like this to input a specific quantity.

```
var customers2 = GetCustomersWithOrderItemQuantity(customers, 1);
```

If you want all orders where at least one item has quantity of 1 then use this.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersWithOrderItemQuantity(List<Customer> customers, int quantity)
    {
        return customers.TakeWhile(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderItems.Any(oi => oi.Quantity == quantity)));
    }
```

The above can be used the same as the other one but will show all orders with at least one order item quantity of 1 in your example above.